# I'm loosing my first scopes when I use ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm still new to angularJS. It's been hours since I've been blocked and unable to find a solution. Can anyone help me, please?

Here is my code:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="main-heading">
            <th>Images</th>
            <th class="long-txt">Descriptif du produit</th>
            <th>Numero de serie</th>
            <th>Prix</th>

            </tr>
            <tr class="cake-bottom" data-ng-repeat="productI in chosenPdtByQte track by $index" > 
              <td class="cakes">
                <div class="product-img2"></div>
                </td>
              <td class="cake-text">
                    <div style="color: #0c517d;">
                    {{productI.nameProduct}} {{productI.id}} {{numSeries.listNumSeries}}
                    <!-- <p>Garantie: {{productI.model.garantie}}</p> -->
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><select name="singleSelect"data-ng-init="fetchNumSerie(productI.id)"data-ng-model="selectedNumSerie[productI.num]" data-ng-options="pdt as pdt for pdt in numSeries.listNumSeries" data-ng-change="saveProduct(productI.num)">
                        </select></td> {{pdt}}

                    <td>
                        <h4>{{productI.price}}</h4>
                    </td>
              </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is I'm trying to display a list of `numSeries` in the select field but I'm only getting the last list relative to the last element of `chosenPdtByQte`.

Can anyone help me please!!

Comment: Suggest you make a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates problem. Not entirely clear what your issue is and we have no idea what `numSeries.listNumSeries` is

Comment: also, it's not clear what `fetchNumSerie(productI.id)` would do, but generally you should avoid the use of `ng-init` except in very specific circumstances.

Comment: well fetchNumSerie(productI.id) presents all the product with the Id productI.id and numSeries.listNumSeries is = {id: productI.id}, liistNumSeries:// Al the series nubers that can have a produc with the id productI.id //}